# A fact about Hermitian matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We know that if $A$ is a hermitian matrix then $X^{*}AX$ is real for all $X$ in $\Bbb{C^{n}}$.Now my question is, is it true that if $X^*AX$ is real for all $X$ in $\Bbb{C^{n}}$ then $A$ has to be hermitian?

My try:

Taking $X$ as $e_{i}$ we are getting $a_{ii}$ to be real.Then taking $X$ to be $e_{i}+e_{j}$ we have $a_{ii}+a_{ij}+a_{ji}+a_{jj}$ to be real.So $a_{ij}+a_{ji}$ has to be real for all i,j.So if $a_{ij}$ is of the form $b+ic$ then,then $a_{ji}$  has to be in the form $p-ic$.But i can't say b=p.That's where i got stuck.

Any help will be appreciated.And i would like to know if there is any conceptual way to do this without these computations.Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is always a 1 by 1  matrix,so u can say that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that $\langle X,AX\rangle=\langle X,A^*X\rangle$ (because these are real numbers) so that $\langle X,TX\rangle=0$ with $T=A-A^*$.

Let $\varphi(X)=X^*TX$ (so here, $\varphi$ is actually $0$). Then, you know that
$$\langle X,TY\rangle=
X^*TY={\frac 12}\bigl (\varphi (X+Y)-\varphi (X)-\varphi (Y)\bigr)+{\frac{\rm {i}}2}\bigl(\varphi (X+{{\rm {i}}}Y)-\varphi (X)-\varphi (Y)\bigr )$$
(this is the polarization identity).

By replacing $\varphi$ by $0$ you get that $\langle X,TY\rangle=0$ for all $X,Y$, so that $T=0$, hence $A$ is self-adjoint.

Comment: this polarization identity turns out to be very useful,can you give some intuition about what does this identity actually mean?

Comment: Well, what its really means is that it sufficies to know the values of $\varphi(x,x)$ (so on the diagonal) to know all the values of $\varphi$. When you are given a quadratic form, this enables you to construct a sesquilinear form which coincided with the quadratic form on the diagonal for example.

Comment: nice very nice . thanks

Comment: i think there should be a minus instead of plus between two brackets.

Comment: This might be $X-iY$ instead of $X+iY$ yes, this depends on wether we chose the inner product to be left sesquilinear or right sesquilinear, sorry

Answer (score 1):

The condition reduces to $ X^{*}(A-A^{*})X = 0 $ for all $ X \in \mathbb{C}^{n} $.

$ (A-A^{*}) $ is normal, so by spectral theorem there is a unitary matrix $ P $ such that $ P^{-1} (A - A^{*}) P $ is diagonal. But our condition forces this diagonal matrix to be $ 0 $, i.e $ (A-A^{*}) = 0 $, as needed.